# Button doesn't do post back in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I'm using the asp file upload control.i didn't wanted to show the user the ugly asp.net control so used some `style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"` to make it hidden.

Here is my html code

```
<a id="a">Browse</a>
<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

And i my jQuery ready function i wrote

```
$(function(){
    $('#a').click(function(){
        $('#file').click();
    });
});
```

But this code doesn't do a postback in ie. I'm testing in ie 9.Although it works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Can any tell me what is wrong with my code.Or else a work around for this.

Comment: try using input instead of asp server control

Comment: input has the same issue in IE

Comment: i always thought IE stops programmatic control of the flle upload control for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at IE Developer tools to see if there are any javascript errors in IE? It is possible that it is not able to find the control with ID 'file' since it is a server control and the ID is generated dynamically when the page is rendered.

Use this to select a server control.

```
$("#<%= file.ClientID %>").click()
```

Or you can use jquery selector.

```
$("[id$='file']")
```

Comment: OK...now this is weird.I tried as u said.Now what is happening is.On first click nothing happens.But if i click once again it does a post back but no file is found in the file upload control's filename

Comment: I am not exactly getting your requirement. When should the page post back? Your code above works for me and when I click on 'a', it opens the file dialog.